# Controlling 'cut' in recursive function to remove an element from a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a function that would remove all the occurrences of an element form a list. I saw that some solutions have already been [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175377/deleting-all-occurrences-of-an-element-from-a-list).  But I'm trying a different approach.
I am basically copying the elements in a new list if they are not equal to what I want to delete.

```
remove(X, [], A, A):-!.
remove(X1, [X1|T1], A, R):-
    remove(X1, T1, A, R).
remove(X2, [H2|T2], A2, R2):-
    remove(X2, T2, [H2 |A2], R2).
```

The first answer is the result I expect, but then it keeps providing more possibilities:

```
?- remove(x, [x, b,c,x,x], [], Result).
Result = [c, b] ;
Result = [x, c, b] ;
Result = [x, c, b] ;
Result = [x, x, c, b] ;
Result = [c, b, x] ;
Result = [x, c, b, x] ;
Result = [x, c, b, x] ;
Result = [x, x, c, b, x].
```

1. [added after edit] Why does it keep providing answers?
2. Is there a way to have it stop at the first result?

Edit: I also just realized that this is also reversing my list :(

Comment: Well you should ask yourself: "Why does it keep providing different results".

Comment: Furthermore note that your program also reverses the list...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: exactly, I don't understand why...

Comment: because you use an accumulator, so as you move through the list, you always *prepend* the item to the accumulator. So if you have a list `[1,4,2,5]`, you start with `[]`, and then you will prepend it with `1`, so `[1]`, next with `4`, so `[4,1]`, you see the pattern?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: (sorry my last comment was ambiguous. I understand why it reverses the list, but I don't understand why it keeps listing possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: if you write `remove(X2, [H2|T2], A2, R2)`, that does not mean that `X2` and `H2` are different, so you need to prevent Prolog from taking that branch. A fundamental aspect of Prolog is that it automatically performs *backtracking*. So the fact that one clause "fires" does not prevents it from other clauses to fire.

A fast fix can be to add a cut to the second clause:

```
remove(X, [], A, A) :- 
    !.
remove(X1, [X1|T1], A, R):-
    !,  % a cut
    remove(X1, T1, A, R).
remove(X2, [H2|T2], A2, R2):-
    remove(X2, T2, [H2 |A2], R2).
```

So in case `X2` and `H2` *can* be unified, Prolog will take the second clause, and then the cut will prevent Prolog taking the third clause.

Another important aspect is that your program *reverses* the list. We can fix this by dropping the accumulator here (you can also work with *difference lists* as an accumulator, but this will introduce too much complexity for now):

```
remove(_, [], []).
remove(X1, [X1|T1], R):-
    !,
    remove(X1, T1, R).
remove(X2, [H2|T2], [H2|R2]):-
    remove(X2, T2, R2).
```

And now you can use it to remove elements from a list that *might* be the same: note that Prolog performs unification, so it will also remove free variables, or partially ungrounded ones that *can* unify.

But: **cuts are dangerous** and will usually result in impure predicates. The idea of Prolog is that you can use predicates in *multiple* directions. For instance you can generate all possible lists with such that the outcome after removing `3` would be `[1,4,2,5]`. In order to do this, we can add a constraint `dif/2`:

```
remove(_, [], []).
remove(X2, [H2|T2], [H2|R2]) :-
    dif(X2, H2),
    remove(X2, T2, R2).
remove(X1, [X1|T1], R):-
    remove(X1, T1, R).
```

we also remove the cut here.

Now we can query it with different tasks:

1. remove all `4`s from the list `[1,4,2,4,4,5]`:

   ```
   ?- remove(4,[1,4,2,4,4,5],X).
   X = [1, 2, 5] ;
   false.
   ```
2. remove *an* element `A` from the list:

   ```
   ?- remove(A,[1,4,2,4,4,5],X).
   X = [1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1) ;
   A = 5,
   X = [1, 4, 2, 4, 4] ;
   A = 2,
   X = [1, 4, 4, 4, 5] ;
   A = 4,
   X = [1, 2, 5] ;
   A = 1,
   X = [4, 2, 4, 4, 5] ;
   false.
   ```
3. generate all lists that could be the input of the removal such that the result is `[1,4,2,5]` (infinite amount of answers):

   ```
   ?- remove(A,L,[1,4,2,5]).
   L = [1, 4, 2, 5],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1) ;
   L = [1, 4, 2, 5, A],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1) ;
   L = [1, 4, 2, 5, A, A],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1) ;
   L = [1, 4, 2, 5, A, A, A],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1) ;
   L = [1, 4, 2, 5, A, A, A, A],
   dif(A, 5),
   dif(A, 2),
   dif(A, 4),
   dif(A, 1)
   ...
   ```
4. what element is removed from the list?

   ```
   ?- remove(A,[1,4,3,2,5],[1,4,2,5]).
   A = 3 ;
   false.

   ?- remove(A,[1,3,4,3,2,5],[1,4,2,5]).
   A = 3 ;
   false.
   ```
5. can we obtain a list `[1,4,2,5]` from removing only one sort of value from `[1,9,4,3,2,5]`? (No!)

   ```
   ?- remove(A,[1,9,4,3,2,5],[1,4,2,5]).
   false.
   ```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks for your help! It's a bit clearer now :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the clause:

```
remove(X2, [H2|T2], A2, R2):-
    remove(X2, T2, [H2 |A2], R2).
```

You need to state explicitly that `X2` differs from `H2`. You can do that by using `dif/2`:

```
remove(X2, [H2|T2], A2, R2):-
        dif(X2,H2),
        remove(X2, T2, [H2 |A2], R2).
```

If you don't state that `X2`,`H2` are different Prolog will try both cases which will lead to keep or throw element H2.